# CREATE statement always creates a ? in front of the first attribute name of the relation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

so whenever I fire a create query there seem to be a hidden '?' character lurking around from somewhere, it gets added right in front of the name of the first attribute. On trying to access this attribute with/without the '?', I keep getting the error: column not found in the field list.

I've tried various syntactic sugars of create statement, one with `, one with ', with space right after create statement. Basically, every combination there is, nothing seems to work. Also, tried rebooting the database Server, din't help.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS temp(usercode varchar(20));
```

Comment: Wait... SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @TheImpaler MySQL, it's actually a heavily discussed bug. I found this thread https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1478 but these comments go way back, I think there might be a solution to this I don't know about.

Comment: "there seem to be a hidden '?' character lurking around" - How do you know there's a `?` somewhere?!

Comment: @JimmyB cause I can see it when I fire desc temp; My points aren't enough to attach an image or else I would've.
Under the field column, it says, ?usercode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get an answer myself. When there are File Operations involved in your application, there are cases when an extra character '/ufeff' gets appended to the attribute name. This character apparently is not visible in standard code editors, although it's possible to see it in Sublime/Notepad++. Thus, when it was evident this was the issue, I replaced the column names in the create statement with:

column_name.replaceAll("/ufeff", "");

This solved the issue, this apparently is a Microsoft office bug and had nothing to do with the way SQL functions.